Are we to assume all the children taken up into Jesus arms and blessed were elect
The question asks what was the blessing Jesus gave ..it can’t have been  a casual , ‘Bless you my child ‘ .. it would have been the blessing of God Himself .. does such blessing mean salvation .. and had Jesus come across a group of children who were all elect . Because if one was not elect how can we reconcile Jesus blessing someone who was damned . Mark 10v16 .

The question is designed to investigate what was the nature of Christ’s blessing .. did  Christ’s blessing bestow salvation on the children .. and were the children all elect because Christ’s blessing would have been great but how does that sit if  a  child was not elect but damned .. some think some are destined from conception to be damned .. I don’t myself .

I don’t have an attitude .. I’m asking questions .

This question isn't about the intended or possible meanings of a scripture; it is about interpretation of a scripture. In particular, it is based on a specific doctrinal belief. "if one was not elect how can we reconcile Jesus blessing someone who was damned" implies a belief that the children have already been assigned salvation or damnation. ¶ The question could be rewritten to make it more obvious exactly what is being asked, and then posted to Christianity.SE rather than here.

It is about the intended or possible meaning of ‘blessed’ in Mark 10v16 and the intended or possible meaning of the word ‘elect’ by Paul .. and how both words and their meaning might be in conflict when Jesus blessed a group of children ..

This verse says nothing about election other than Jesus' example of wanting to bless children.  So should we.  This question might be better phrased as something like, "What is the meaning of the Greek verb χεῖρας in this context?" or similar.

Well, Judas Iscariot was a child in so far as spiritual life is concerned. He walked with Jesus for three years, listened to the Lord' a discourses and even participated in the Last Supper. But he got lost !
